# CS50 problem set 3 (tideman); I keep getting an error on my lock_pairs function that it "did not lock all pairs". (Not using new function cycle)

Tags: c, cs50

Link to Problem set: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/3/tideman/

So far every function works except lock_pairs function (near the bottom). The lock_pairs array starts off with all false. I made two for loops that check if the loser value is greater than the winner, if so then it returns false. Otherwise the lock_pairs slot is changed to true. I get no errors regarding cycles but the check50 states not all pairs lock.

**I keep getting this error:**
*lock_pairs locks all pairs when no cycles
Cause
lock_pairs did not lock all pairs*

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// preferences[i][j] is number of voters who prefer i over j
int preferences[MAX][MAX];

// locked[i][j] means i is locked in over j
bool locked[MAX][MAX];

// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
}
pair;

// Array of candidates
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];

int pair_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[]);
void record_preferences(int ranks[]);
void add_pairs(void);
void sort_pairs(void);
void lock_pairs(void);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: tideman [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i] = argv[i + 1];
    }

    // Clear graph of locked in pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            locked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    pair_count = 0;
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Query for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // ranks[i] is voter's ith preference
        int ranks[candidate_count];

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            if (!vote(j, name, ranks))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }

        record_preferences(ranks);

        printf("\n");
    }

    add_pairs();
    sort_pairs();
    lock_pairs();
    print_winner();
    return 0;
}

// Update ranks given a new vote
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(name, candidates[i]) == 0)
        {
            ranks[rank] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Update preferences given one voter's ranks
void record_preferences(int ranks[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int col = i + 1; col < candidate_count; col++)
        {
            preferences[ranks[i]][ranks[col]] += 1;
        }
    }

    //self check by print out results
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            printf("%i ", preferences[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}

// Record pairs of candidates where one is preferred over the other
void add_pairs(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < candidate_count; col++)
        {
            if (preferences[i][col] > preferences[col][i])
            {
                pairs[pair_count].winner = i;
                pairs[pair_count].loser = col;

                pair_count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    pair temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pair_count - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] < preferences[pairs[j + 1].winner][pairs[j + 1].loser])
            {
                temp = pairs[j];
                pairs[j] = pairs[j + 1];
                pairs[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    //self check by print out results
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        printf("%i, %i\n", pairs[i].winner, pairs[i].loser);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
// create a second for loop within the 1st one that checks if prior [loser][winner] are true. If they are, then it will create a cycle
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pair_count; j++)
        {
            if (locked[pairs[i].loser][pairs[j].winner] == true)
            {
                locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    //self check by print out results
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            printf("%i ", locked[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}

// Print the winner of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    return;
}
```

I tried changing the false value to true if the condition was met (the loser value wasn't greater than the winner value - checks if the array says true). This should create a locked gird of values that are true based on pair strength and no edges will loop back to a larger number.

I know others create a new function called iscycle but the problem set states this,
*You should not modify anything else in tideman.c other than the implementations of the vote, record_preferences, add_pairs, sort_pairs, lock_pairs, and print_winner functions (and the inclusion of additional header files, if you’d like). You are permitted to add additional functions to tideman.c, so long as you do not change the declarations of any of the existing functions.*
Therefore, I am trying not to create a new function to solve this.

Comment: `"You are permitted to add additional functions to tideman.c, so long as you do not change the declarations of any of the existing functions."`

Answer (score 0):

> I made two for loops that check if the loser value is greater than the winner

By doing so, you detect only trivial cycles with two nodes, not cycles which span three or more nodes.

> if so then it returns false

It's not that *it returns false*, rather it sets `locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = false`, which it must not do, since the very purpose of `locked` is that the *algorithm locks in the strongest edges first* and never unlocks them.